# A special word-play crossword

Tags: wordplay, cryptic-clues, crosswords

[image: crossword]

**Vertical**
1. I could be cash but a key buggered me.
3. Go spell!
4. Quiet! Not inside!
5. She was standing behind the arc.
6. A whole of 10.!
7. Apparantly, everyone needs reputation and food. Hopefully, they don't mix them.
9. A sweet upper clothing.
11. A hell of an operating system.
12. An inspiration for artists entertains literally (5)
13. A boss weighs a lot.
14. Voting with a musical instrument contaminates (7)
15. A marine child sticks spices. (6)
16. A donkey set with an acquisition. (5)

**Horizontal**
2. An owl saved me from the frying pan
8. Many traps. Or was it the other way around?
10. Super short, yet super long.

PS. For clarity, I have added the letter count to the cryptic clue ones.

Comment: Aaah sorry, do you not want the length?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, I just added the count to the cryptic clues - for clarity - added a PS to the puzzle. :)

Comment: Sorry, you had the wrong tag. Use [cryptic-crosswords].

Comment: @Scratch---Cat, there is a reason I did not use the tag [cryptic-crosswords] - not all of the clues fit into the [cryptic-clues] category. Some are more [wordplay]. That is why the crossword is not a true cryptic crossword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1= Monkey (@dcyfj)
> 2 = <strike>Egg</strike> Ego (@dcfyj)
> 3 = Gospel (@BeastlyGerbil)
> 4 = Shout (@MOehm)
> 5 = Archer (@MOehm)
> 6 = Cholera (@Will)
> 7 = Repeat (@MOehm)
> 8 = Strap (@Sconibulus)
> 9 = Sugarcoat (@Will)
> 10 = Era (@Sconibulus)
> 11 = Helios (@Sconibulus)
> 12 = Amuse (@Sconibulus)
> 13 = Boston (@Sconibulus)
> 14 = Pollute (@Will)
> 15 = Season (@MOehm)
> 16 = Asset (@RandAl'Thor)

Here's an image version:

> [image: Crossword Solution]

The blue words spell out:

> YOU ARE THE BEST 
> But because I didn't get many This should regarded as a message to all mentioned above